# DNN Too many redirects

Tags: dotnetnuke-7

Our dnn version is 07.04.00 (353). We have an external system that redirects the user to some page. In order, the user will see the page he must have specific role i.e. this page only visible for users that have this role. If the user doesn't have this role he should be redirected to the home page.

Using chrome developer tools we see that the page get "You+do+not+have+access+to+view+this+page+within+the+website", dnn then redirect to Default.aspx where there it gets "=An%20unexpected%20error%20has%20occurred". It then try redirect to the page again and it enter into infinite loop of redirection.

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Log4Net files in \Portals_default\Logs for more a detailed error message.